# Read flow file attribute/content to processor property

Tags: apache-nifi, flowfile

I want to set a property of a processor based on the contents of the last flowfile that came through.

Example: I instantiate the flowfile with the processor `GenerateFlowFile` and with the custom text `${now()}` as the current timestamp during the creation of the flowFile.

I want to have a processor (which kind is irrelevant to me) to read the content of the flowfile (the timestamp) to the processor's custom property `property_name`.  Afterwards I want to be able to potentially query the processor via the REST-API and read that property from the processor.

Initially I thought I could do that with the `ExtractText` processor, but it extracts text based on regex  and writes it back to the flowfile, while I want to save that information in the processor until the next flowfile arrives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it via NiFi. When the processor running you can't update its config.

Maybe you can use state variables on UpdateAttribute?

> Stateful Usage
>
> By selecting "store state locally" option for the "Store State"
> property UpdateAttribute will not only store the evaluated properties
> as attributes of the FlowFile but also as stateful variables to be
> referenced in a recursive fashion. This enables the processor to
> calculate things like the sum or count of incoming FlowFiles. A
> dynamic property can be referenced as a stateful variable like so:
>
> Dynamic Property key : theCount value :
> `${getStateValue("theCount"):plus(1)}` This example will keep a count of
> the total number of FlowFiles that have passed through the processor.
> To use logic on top of State, simply use the "Advanced Usage" of
> UpdateAttribute. All Actions will be stored as stateful attributes as
> well as being added to FlowFiles. Using the "Advanced Usage" it is
> possible to keep track of things like a maximum value of the flow so
> far. This would be done by having a condition of
> `"${getStateValue("maxValue"):lt(${value})}"` and an action of
> attribute:"maxValue", value:"${value}". The "Stateful Variables
> Initial Value" property is used to initialize the stateful variables
> and is required to be set if running statefully. Some logic rules will
> require a very high initial value, like using the Advanced rules to
> determine the minimum value. If stateful properties reference other
> stateful properties then the value for the other stateful properties
> will be an iteration behind. For example, attempting to calculate the
> average of the incoming stream requires the sum and count. If all
> three properties are set in the same UpdateAttribute (like below) then
> the Average will always not include the most recent values of count
> and sum:
>
> Count key : theCount value : `${getStateValue("theCount"):plus(1)} Sum> key : theSum value : ${getStateValue("theSum"):plus(${flowfileValue})}`
> Average key : theAverage value :
> `${getStateValue("theSum"):divide(getStateValue("theCount"))}` Instead,
> since average only relies on theCount and theSum attributes (which are
> added to the FlowFile as well) there should be a following Stateless
> UpdateAttribute which properly calculates the average. In the event
> that the processor is unable to get the state at the beginning of the
> onTrigger, the FlowFile will be pushed back to the originating
> relationship and the processor will yield. If the processor is able to
> get the state at the beginning of the onTrigger but unable to set the
> state after adding attributes to the FlowFile, the FlowFile will be
> transferred to "set state fail". This is normally due to the state not
> being the most up to date version (another thread has replaced the
> state with another version). In most use-cases this relationship
> should loop back to the processor since the only affected attributes
> will be overwritten. Note: Currently the only "stateful" option is to
> store state locally. This is done because the current implementation
> of clustered state relies on Zookeeper and Zookeeper isn't designed
> for the type of load/throughput UpdateAttribute with state would
> demand. In the future, if/when multiple different clustered state
> options are added, UpdateAttribute will be updated.

Comment: This is great! Took me a while, but I was able to make use of the `theCount` example to create a counter for the number of flow files which pass through the processor - not exactly a timestamp, but the next best thing as I can track whether the number went up since the last time I checked. The big plus: I can get the state of a processor including the current value of `theCount` via the REST-API: `/processors/{id}/state`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ivan I was able to create a full working solution - for future reference:

1. Instantiate flowfiles with e.g. a `GenerateFlowFile` processor and add a custom property "myproperty" and value `${now()}`  (note: you can add this property to the flow files in any processor, doesn't have to be a `GenerateFlowFile` processor)
2. Have a `UpdateAttribute` processor with the option (under processor properties) **Store State** set to `Store state locally`.
3. Add a custom property in the `UpdateAttribute` processor with the name **readable_property** and set it to the value `${'myproperty'}`.

The state of the processor now contains the value of the last flowfile (e.g. with a timestamp of when the attribute was added to the flowfile).

Added Bonus:

4. Get the value of the stateful processor (and hence the value of the last flowfile that passed through (!) ) via the REST-API and a GET on the URI `/nifi-api/processors/{id}/state`

The JSON which gets returned contains the following lines:

```
{
"key":"readable_property"
,"value":"Wed Apr 14 11:13:40 CEST 2021"
,"clusterNodeId":"some-id-0d8eb6052"
,"clusterNodeAddress":"some-host:port-number"
}
```

Then you just have to parse the JSON for the value.

Answer (score -1):

You should use UpdateAttribute processor.
You can read several methods - f.e. [Update attributes based on content in NiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910721/update-attributes-based-on-content-in-nifi)

Comment: That link is a completely different topic - I don't want to add an attribute to the flow file... I want to update **the processor's property** *not the flow file.*